# Selecting an item (In this case a troop) from in game hot bar and deploy it in the battlefield using c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, game-development

Just a simple hint will help me , what does this system calls ? Imagine a game like clash of clans when you choose your troops in the hot bar and touch the game field (ground) and they deploy and seek target to destroy, I will appreciate if can help me with the script method or a name or hint so I can study it more !thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0B6K.jpg)

Comment: Hot bar is made up of UI Buttons. Clicking a button selects a prefab to instantiate, clicking the battlefield with a prefab selected will trigger the game to instantiate the prefab. You'd have to transform the mouse click location to world space to get the location to instantiate.

Comment: Thank you,that’s what I needed,I can start research now about instantiate,thank u